# How to copy old document and create new document in mongodb if particular filed value found in any collection in the DB

Tags: mongodb

I have around 20 collection in our mongoDB.
One document in one collection has some relationship/association with a document in another collection.
We have one common field **"executionId" : "some old value"** in all the documents across the collections.
collection may have one or more documents

I want to iterate through all the collection and if any document matches **"executionId" : "some old value"** then i want to copy that document and create new document with new value **"executionId" : "some new value "** in the same collection.

I want to repeat this for all the collection in my mongoDB.

For Example. Below are my collection

```
collection_one
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ef615b87127ee8d00229473"),
  "executionId" : "some old value",
  "application" : "app1",
  "status" : "Started"
  
}

collection_two
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ef615b87127ee8d00229455"),
  "executionId" : "some old value",
  "isOrder" : false,
  "form" : false,
  "officerNumber" : "T643",
  "phoneNumber" : "0482",
  "createdDate" : ISODate("2020-06-26T15:35:20.889Z"),
  "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2020-06-26T15:35:25.045Z")
  
}

collection_three
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5ef615b87127ee8d00229466"),
  "executionId" : "some old value",
  "application" : "app1",
  "country" : "country"
  
}
```

After I execute the update query in shell prompt. I want them to look like this.

```
 collection_one
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5ef615b87127ee8d00229473"),
      "executionId" : "some new value",
      "application" : "app1",
      "status" : "Started"
      
    }
    
    collection_two
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ef615b87127ee8d00229455"),
      "executionId" : "some new value",
      "isOrder" : false,
      "form" : false,
      "officerNumber" : "T643",
      "phoneNumber" : "0482",
      "createdDate" : ISODate("2020-06-26T15:35:20.889Z"),
      "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2020-06-26T15:35:25.045Z")
      
    }
    
    collection_three
    {
     "_id" : ObjectId("5ef615b87127ee8d00229466"),
      "executionId" : "some new value",
      "application" : "app1",
      "country" : "country"
      
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) for that.

```
db.collectionName.updateMany(
    { executionId: 'some old value' },
    { $set: { executionId : 'some new value'} }
);
```

since you want to do this for all the collections in your database, you can try this:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(collection => {
    db[collection].updateMany({ executionId: 'some old value' },  { $set: { executionId : 'some new value'} })
});
```